# How to display each player's updated score to every player's UI who are connected to the game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am developing a real-time multiplayer Quiz game in which the no of players connected in a game-room is limited to 2,which means that each player will have only one opponent.I am trying to display both the player's scores to both the players each time they click on a question's option;like this: Score1:20 Score2:10 similar to Quizup game but i am unable to display the opponent's score.
I have used nodejs,socket.io for the server side and javascript for the front-end.I have tried sending the scores each time to the server and the server stores the scores it in mongodb server but i am unable to fetch the respective scores of each player .

game.html and  main.js(client side) :

```js
function answer(ans) {
  var z = document.getElementById('option' + ans);
  var choice = z.innerHTML;
  var a = new Date().getTime();
  var diff1 = sTime - a;
  var seconds1 = 0 - Math.floor(diff1 / 1000);
  console.log(seconds1);
  Disable_Buttons();
  var l = 10 - seconds1;
  if (choice == questions[x].answer) {
    scores += l;
  } else {
    scores = scores;
  }
    socket.emit('score',{
            scores:scores,
            id:socket.id
        });
     socket.on('leaderboard',(data)=>{
    document.getElementById('scores').innerHTML = 'SCORE1: '+data.points;
    document.getElementById('all_scores').innerHTML = 'SCORE2: '+ data.points;
});
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="button0" onclick="answer('0')" style="display:none"><span id="option0"></span></button> <br>
  <button id="button1" onclick="answer('1')" style="display:none"><span id="option1"></span></button> <br>
  <button id="button2" onclick="answer('2')" style="display:none"><span id="option2"></span></button> <br>
  <button id="button3" onclick="answer('3')" style="display:none"><span id="option3"></span></button> <br>
</div>

<hr style="margin-top: 50px">
<footer>
  <h2 id="message"></h2>

  <h3 id='scores'></h3>
  <h3 id='all_scores'></h3>
```

server.js

```
  socket.on('score',(data)=>{
    db.collection('Scores').insertOne({
        id:data.id,
        score:data.scores
    },(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
           return console.log('unable to insert',err);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops,undefined,2));
    });

    socket.to(room_id).emit('leaderboard',{
        points: db.collection("Scores").findOne({id:data.id},{id:0,_id:0})
    });



});
```

Comment: This is quite easy using Firebase, websockets and Observables: https://firebase.google.com. It auto syncs in-memory object -> db -> other app listeners.

Comment: The part of your code which is likely to be relevant is where the scores are sent and received by the client and server, which we can't see here. Add that to your question.

Comment: i have edited it , i didnt mention the server part coz the scores emiiting event from the server to the client is not right . Thats why i was hesitant to mention it!

Comment: @Diodeus-james i want to create on my own like i have done the remaining things except the scores displaying part wiz i m unable to do it. Thank you!